# Dataflow How do I write PubSub Message to GCS induvidual file

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a scenario, where I have a streaming dataflow. The logic is to read json data from a PubSub subscription
and make an api call to external system. In case if external system is not reachable, I need to persist the json data to GCS for later reprocessing. I could able to write the failure data to GCS but the challenge I have is instead of individual files, it's getting written to single file between the window mentioned. Is there any way I could write each pubsub message to GCS as individual files with unique file name based on value from each json data.

```
    final TupleTag<String> failureData =new TupleTag<String>(){};
    PCollectionTuple APIOutputCollection= pipeline.apply("Read PubSub Events",PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))
           .apply("Send to Apigee",ParDo.of(new APICall()).withOutputTags(successData,TupleTagList.of(failureData)));
    
    
     APIOutputCollection.get(failureData)
     .apply(
                options.getWindowDuration() + " Window",
                Window.into(FixedWindows.of(DurationUtils.parseDuration(options.getWindowDuration()))))
        .apply(
                "Write File(s)",
                TextIO.write()
                    .withWindowedWrites()
                    .withNumShards(options.getNumShards())
                    .to(
                        WindowedFilenamePolicy.writeWindowedFiles()
                            .withOutputDirectory(options.getOutputDir())
                            .withOutputFilenamePrefix((options.getOutputFileNamePrefix())
                            .withShardTemplate(options.getOutputShardTemplate())
                            .withSuffix(".json")
                            .withTempDirectory(
                            NestedValueProvider.of(
                            maybeUseUserTempLocation(options.getUserTempLocation(),options.getOutputDirectory()),
                           (SerializableFunction<String, ResourceId>)
                           input -> FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(input))));
```

Comment: Storing data in file? Why not republishing a message in another PubSub topic to persist them? You have up to 30 days to consume them (your "later processing")

Comment: I have a scheduled job to read data from storage at regular intervals. So writing it to storage was proposed for us instead of pub sub.